# Android Radio App that streams my mp3 from a dropbox server

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming

I have a dropbox media server that has a collection of mp3 files that I want to stream onto an android application.

I know that using the "MediaPlayer" is the best way to go in the API.

How my main concern is how do I automate the process, where music is being played one after another? As if it was like an internet radio app?

Could someone please point me in the correct location for guides or display example code would be great thank you in advance.

Comment: So just do that. Write the code to play one track, and then another right after it. You have to actually sit down and start experimenting with the code if you've never done this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the music files names in an arraylist (e.g songs) then implement onCompletionListener then set it to your media player. Inside the listener restart the media player to play the next item.

```
myMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
      arg0.release();
      if (counter < songs.size()) {
        counter++;
        arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songs.get(counter);
        arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        arg0.start();
      }
    }
```

Comment: I sort of understand this, but this will surely affect my data source? As I'm now taking it from an array? In addition, I get an error on your " arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songs.get(counter);" stating it cannot resolve method

Comment: Okay I have wrapped it using Uri.parse so code is now mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songs.get(counter))); but how do i link my datasource to the array list?

Comment: if you know the number of songs already and have them in an array, no need for the arraylist. Since you already have song names in array, just iterate over the array like this : your_array[counter]

Answer (score 0):

If the server gives apps audio files;put the files in a queue and play them using mediaplayer or another audio player.
Get first song from server and start playing it, meanwhile continue downloading other songs one by one.